# Android image sharing app

Tags: android, sharing, mms

Hello everyone i need some help. I have a android app that is a gallary and when they choose the image you can press menu share and it will go to a text box and some quotes where they can select a quote or write their own text and then pick where they want to share to.

My problem is that when i try to share to Facebook or MMS it only shows the text and says **"unable to attach. File not supported"**. But when i choose to share with gmail it has the text and image and everything is fine.

I was just wondering if someone has any idea how to fix this, and if so can someone tell me how.

Thanks in advanced,

Zach

Answer (score 1):

Are you sharing vi an `Intent.createChooser()`, using the official Facebook app?

The official FB app only allow you to share an url (www.example.com) and it will grab the image and the text from this site before submitting the post.

Comment: Here is what im using (sorry it was too long to put in one comment)---->

Comment: `Bitmap resourceImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), selectedImage);
File externalStorageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
resourceImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
byte b[] = bytes.toByteArray();
try {
    externalStorageFile.createNewFile();
    OutputStream filoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(externalStorageFile);
    filoutputStream.write(b);
    filoutputStream.flush();
    filoutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
`

Comment: `}
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + externalStorageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_share_title)));
        TextActivity.this.finish();
}
}`

Comment: This will work with GMail, for example, but not with Facebook. With facebook will only work sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "www.yoursite.com/folder"); And it will get an image and extract a text to build the post. That's not a bug, that's the recognized official behaviour with the FB app :-(

Comment: Ah ok thank you! Do you know why the text messaging app has the same problem?